# Как в Visual Studio в post-build событии задать команду создания environment переменной?

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Краткий вопрос сформулировать сложно, поэтому опишу ситуацию.

Есть test.exe, это результат компиляции юнит-тестов на основе Boost.Test. Компилируется в MS Visual Studio. В целях быстрого запуска тестов без переключения в ком.строку и мне нужно задать в post-build event запуск двух команд: 1) set test_files=../../test-data 2) test.exe

Но в post-build ивенте не вижу способа задать работу двух команд. Как это сделать без вынесения в bat-файл?

*UPD*
Вариант с оператором && тоже не особо подходит. Пока именно он применяется

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко, то в файле проекте *.vcxproj набор команд должен быть прописан вот таким образом:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
  <Command>set c=123
echo %c%</Command>
</PostBuildEvent>
```

В качестве разделителя между командами используется перевод строки, а не `;`, как в обычной командной строке для последовательного выполнения команд.

Сделать это можно двумя способами: отредактировать текстовый файл напрямую, или для редактирования использовать команду  в настройках проекта.